# AWS SQS send message with KMS ID on cli

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, aws-cli

I have an SQS Queue encrypted with a KMS Customer Master Key (CMK)

I can't get the `--message-attributes` syntax right to add the KMS key id when using the `send-message` cli command

```
aws sqs send-message --queue-url "queue/url" --message-body "testing" --message-attributes '{"keyId": {"DataType":"String", "StringValue":"mKeyId"}}'
```

The error I get back is

```
An error occurred (KMS.NotFoundException) when calling the SendMessage operation: Invalid keyId (Service: AWSKMS; Status Code: 400; Error Code: NotFoundException; Request ID: 02cae15e-bf78-11e7-c001-f9dff348cb7e)
```

The key is the correct key, and I've also tried with the key alias.

Couldn't find anything in the [SQS docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/Welcome.html)

What am I getting wrong with the syntax?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out I created a bad queue via cloudformation

When reading the Cloudformation docs for SQS, the [`KmsMasterKeyId`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-sqs-queues.html#aws-sqs-queue-kmsmasterkeyid) I had included my CMK alias, when you should only use an alias when using the AWS managed sse (`/alias/aws/sqs`).

When updating to my actual key id, the cli command I used worked just fine

```
aws sqs send-message --queue-url "queue/url" --message-body "testing" --message-attributes '{"keyId": {"DataType":"String", "StringValue":"mKeyId"}}'
```